# Access codeigniter session on unity 3d

Tags: codeigniter, unity-game-engine

I have a website made with codeigniter but one of the php document its generated by unity to execute a web application ,the problem is that I have to access to a session data from codeigniter `$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in);`
but I can't access yo this data from the unity webplayer

Comment: I don't know anything about unity web player or how it access sessions, but I do know that the codeigniter session library does not use native PHP sessions. This is most likely the issue, I would recommend searching the CI forums for a native sessions library and try use it with that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using CodeIgniter (CI) 2?

In CI 2 you cannot access the session through the superglobal $_SESSION. If you need to use the CI session library than you could do it by enabling session loggin in the database. Then from your unity application you can query the CI session table.

Otherwise you can use a native session library for CI 2, like this one: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session. With a native session library you can access session data through the superglobal $_SESSION.

In CI 3 the session library has been rewritten and uses the superglobal $_SESSION again. So no need to use a third party native session library there.

Comment: I'm using CI 3,but I cannot access to logged_in throus $_SESSION,the file where I'm tring to access to logged_in variable is not a CI class

Comment: What do you see when you run var_dump($_SESSION);exit; in the unity file? Can you post the unity file?

Answer (score -1):

please print $_SESSION to get all session variable and seeing your code, to access logged_in variable, please use it following.

```
        $logged_in=$this->session->userdata('logged_in);
```

now $logged_in variable contain logged_in information, please check.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer